# GridView button - yes/no option

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I cannot figure out how to make this situation. I have ASP.NET application with webpage showing GridView linked to database - showing books which can be rented. I want to have button at each line, so user can click and rent this book. After click, user should get messageBox with question like "Do you really want to rent this book? and Yes/No option and in c# code I want to gent this answer with line, where this button was clicked and handle it properly.

So far I was able to create this code :

GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="Žádné datové záznamy k zobrazení." OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="author" SortExpression="author" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="genre" HeaderText="genre" SortExpression="genre" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="availability" HeaderText="availability" SortExpression="availability" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="owner" HeaderText="owner" SortExpression="owner" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="isbn" HeaderText="isbn" SortExpression="isbn" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="barcode" HeaderText="barcode" SortExpression="barcode" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="amount" SortExpression="amount" />
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="text" Text="button" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Script to handle question :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to rent this book?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

and in my C# code I have

```
        protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "text")
        {
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                showMessage("You clicked YES!");
            }
            else
            {
                showMessage("You clicked NO!");
            }
            //GridView2.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[0].Text); -> cell value of clicked row
        }
        }
    private void showMessage(string text)
    {
        string script = "alert(\"" + text + "\");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
```

But I cannot figure out, how to add script to gridView button, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClientClick for that

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="text" Text="button" OnClientClick="return Confirm();"/>
```

And Your javascript function look like

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Confirm() {

    if (confirm("Do you want to rent this book?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

No need to store value in hidden field because if user click on 'No' then page won't post back.

Comment: OnClientClick is not valid for gridView button, I cannot use this solution, already tried

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out how to do it by myself, button needs to be transfered to templateField and then it´s possible to add onClientClick